# Localization not changing in .NET Core 2.0 with Angular 4 template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We are using ASP.NET Boilerplate version 3.3.0 in .NET Core 2.0 with Angular 4 template.

The localization is not working.

I am getting the same language set to `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` every time.

When I change the language on the client side, the cookie is set properly but the current language is not getting updated.

Comment: Yes, it is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This has been fixed in v3.4.0 of the template: [`507eecf`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/507eecff8a73cc70cf934d1496474710146693bf)

Essentially, this involved a server call in **topbar-languageswitch.component.ts**:

```js
// Before
changeLanguage(languageName: string): void {
  abp.utils.setCookieValue(
    "Abp.Localization.CultureName",
    languageName,
    new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 365 * 86400000), //5 year
    abp.appPath
  );

  location.reload();
}

// After
changeLanguage(languageName: string): void {
    const input = new ChangeUserLanguageDto();
    input.languageName = languageName;

    this._userService.changeLanguage(input).subscribe(() => {
        abp.utils.setCookieValue(
            'Abp.Localization.CultureName',
            languageName,
            new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 365 * 86400000), //5 year
            abp.appPath
        );

        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```